# getting undefined from useSelector react-redux hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that dispatches action to the reducer using useDispatch hook inside useEffect. I only wants it to happen once on first component render. Then when I try to set the results from the store using useSelector hook I am getting undefined. Here is my code:

```
const SingleHotel = props => {
  //GETTING HOTEL ID FROM REACT-ROUTER-DOM PROPS
  const {
    match: {
      params: { id }
    }
  } = props

  //INITIALIZE USE DISPATCH REDUX HOOK.
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  //ACCESSING HOTEL DETAILS STATE FROM THE REDUX STORE.
  const hotelDetails = useSelector(state => state.SingleHotel)

  //DISPATCHING HOTEL DETAILS TO THE REDUCER.
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSingleHotel(id))
  }, [])

  return <div>Single hotel page {console.log(hotelDetails)}</div>
}
```

I am console logging state from the store in the JSX but I get 'undefined'.
However, when I check the results in the Redux dev tools it appears correctly.
Here is how it looks:
[image: Redux dev tools image]

Comment: check the capitalization. You use `state.SingleHotel` in the code, but the screenshot of the dev tools shows `singleHotel`.

Comment: Yes that worked my mistake. However, it still goes to  the same issue because now when I try to console.log(hotelDetails.fields.hotelName) in the JSX I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'hotelName' of undefined I think it is because JSX is rendered before hook finished pulling data from the store. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: How does your `reducer` look like? Normally one would use an action creator or dispatch an object with type and a payload. How's the shape of object returned by `fetchSingleHotel(id)`?

Comment: fetchSingleHotel(id) returns object with property fields and nested properties inside it such as hotelName, city etc. I've realized that the initialState of my reducer is an empty object and when I try to set initial state to include shape of the API response the error disapears. Is this approach will be correct or any other solutions for this issue are preferred?

Comment: That, or write your code to expect the possibility that the data doesn't exist.

Comment: What I usually do is to push the actual data I need to work with one level down and have all kinds of control flags that other parts of the system can read. So you have something like this in your state singleHotel { fetched: false, isFetching: false, data: { sys: <your details>, fields: <your details> }, <other flags you find useful> }.  This way your useEffect will check to see if the data has been fetched or isFetching and will dispatch only when both are false. If fetched is true, you check further to see if the id matches the params, if not, fire off a fetch, and set local state...

Comment: If you will find the above comment useful, let me know, so I can work up a full-blown answer for you.